# How to make a simple GUI?

Tags: pi-3, python, gps

I recently had follow [this tutorial](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/email-alert-system-on-location-change-with-raspberry-pi-and-gps-module/#comment-354251) which basically is about making your raspberry pi send email notification every three seconds on the location of your device.

The thing that is missing now is, I wanted to have like a simple GUI for users to click a button on that it can start and stop the delivery of the email message or maybe user could enter an input to change the time between every message. I don't have enough knowledge on how to build a GUI. Can anyone guide me on how to build a simple GUI for this project.

Comment: Probably worth looking at Python and some web site interface. That is the easiest way to start of as Python on Pi is easy to take web requests and do things natively on the Pi system.

Comment: For really simple stuff that you can add to your existing software you could try the [zenity](https://www.tecmint.com/zenity-creates-graphical-gtk-dialog-boxes-in-command-line-and-shell-scripts/) package to show simple dialogues and pop-ups. For a more complete GUI I've heard [kivy](https://kivy.org/) being recommended, especially on small screens and touchscreens.

Answer (score -1):

You want guizero (a zero-boilerplate wrapper for Tk): https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/